# How to install the millennial package in miktex (Windows)

Tags: packages, math-fonts, installing-fonts

Well, there are some questions about how to install packages that are not in the package repository. The most famous probably is [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1).

I'm traying to install the package `millennial` (you can see this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383946/new-century-schoolbook-with-millennial-math-not-available-in-texlive-2016) and the links mentioned that) that is not avaible from the package repository. I have downloaded the files (the previous question has a comment with a direct link) but I don't know how to continue.

The problem of this package is that it doesn't include either `.ins`file or `.dtx` file, so I can't follow the steps provided in the above link. Instead of that, I haves just run my `MikTeX` console and included the path folder containing the files of the package to the other paths, you know, settings-directories-add, as it is said [here](https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console).

It doesn't work and I can't use the package. What can I do? How can I install this package? Let me say I have refreshed the FNDB and the FMF after including the new directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference from egreg in the other question links to a tar.bz2. Unpack this somewhere outside miktex. Inside the tar is a folder texmf. Copy this folder somewhere (again outside miktex). Then go to the miktex console and add the texmf as a new root in settings -> tab directories.

Then run on a command line

```
 initexmf --edit-config-file=updmap
```

This will open a updmap.cfg in the editor. Add

```
 Map millennial.map
```

to the file and click on "save".

Run in the miktex console (user mode) in the tasks menu the entry `refresh font map files`. Then test if the font works ...