# I want to increase the thickness of the writing because it is thin for me

Tags: fonts

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}




\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newframedtheorem}{O{}momo}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {%
    \IfNoValueTF{#5}
     {\newtheorem{#2}{#4}}
     {\newtheorem{#2}{#4}[#5]}%
    }
   {\newtheorem{#2}[#3]{#4}}
  \tcolorboxenvironment{#2}{#1}%
}

\newtheoremstyle{theoremddq}% name of the style to be used  
{\topsep}% measure of space to leave above the theorem. E.g.: 3pt  
{\topsep}% measure of space to leave below the theorem. E.g.: 3pt  
{\itshape}% name of font to use in the body of the theorem   
{2mm}%measure of space to indent   
{\bfseries}% name of head font   
{}%punctuation between head and body   
{ }% space after theorem head; " "= normal interword space   
{\underline{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}:} {\underline{\thmnote{\textit{(#3)}}}} }









\newframedtheorem[   enhanced jigsaw,   colback={white!70!white},  
   colframe=black,   coltitle=black,   boxrule=1pt,   sharp corners,  
   breakable, ]{remark*}{Remarque}



\newframedtheorem[   enhanced jigsaw,   colback={white!70!white},  
   colframe=black,   coltitle=black,   boxrule=1pt,   sharp corners,  
   breakable]{remarks*}[remark*]{Remarques}

   \newframedtheorem[   enhanced jigsaw,   colback={white!70!white},  
   colframe=red,   coltitle=black,   boxrule=1pt,   sharp corners,  
   breakable, ]{defi}{Définition}


\newtheorem{thech}{Exercice} 

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}
Let G be a finite abelian group and let V be an
irreducible representation
 \end{defi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to change font, you can look at https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/ for alternatives.

Comment: I want to control the thickness that suits me

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100577/fatter-computer-modern for possibilities to make the default font thicker.

Comment: the font stroke thickness is not a user-settable parameter, computer modern is a very light font, perhaps you would prefer a Times Roman clone, try adding `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`

Comment: David Carlisie , Resembles package times ,

Comment: @mohammed yes but better to use the package I suggested than the old times package.