# 2000´s Typesetter Latex Style

Tags: templates, font-encodings

Recently I found this document: [https://public.websites.umich.edu/~hlm/nzm/clintman.pdf](https://public.websites.umich.edu/%7Ehlm/nzm/clintman.pdf)
(sorry to refer to a link but I assure you that its safe)

My question is if someone would help me to make a little template that generates the same PDF like in the link, the content does not matter but for the sake of this question we can use some of the text in the document.

I tried my best to create a template and got this

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,scrextend} 
\usepackage[T4]{fontenc}   
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}  
\font\BF cmbx30 scaled \magstep2
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\Huge \textbf{Hallo}
\end{center}
The program FacTab produces a table of least prime divisors of odd numbers, up to $10^9$. The                     values are calculated by dividing small primes into the numbers in the desired range, until the only numbers for which a least prime divisor has not been found are prime. Let $p$ be a given prime number. The least composite integer $n$ such that $p$ is the least prime factor of $n$ is $n=p^2$. (In this connection, recall Problem 24. on p. 30 of NZM.) Thus if one is to prepare a table of least prime factors of integers in an interval $[a, b]$, then it is useful to have on hand a table of all primes $p \leq b^{1 / 2}$. In the case of FacTab, the intervals considered are of the form $[10 N, 10 N+200]$ with $N \leq 10^8$. Since 31607 and 31627 are consecutive primes, and since $$31607^2<10^9+200<31627^2$$
\end{document}
```

If you compare the output of this document with the pdf, you can see that the letters in clintman.pdf are **thicker** and like a typesetter font.

Maybe someone knows how they wrote their tex-file and can help me, I really like this old LaTeX style. Just using T4 gives thin letters but its not the same like in the doc.

Hint: I noticed that there are TEX files on the website [https://public.websites.umich.edu/~hlm/nzm/nzmsupp.html](https://public.websites.umich.edu/%7Ehlm/nzm/nzmsupp.html) and they have this in their code

```
\input amstex
\documentstyle{math575}
\vsize 8.5truein
\font\BF cmbx10 scaled \magstep2
```

Sadly the tex files cannot be compiled in Overleaf.

Original File

[image]

My File:

[image]

PS: More examples of this type of letters are here:

- https://proglang.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/swt/2005/exercises/pflichtenheft_sol.pdf
- [https://people.math.wisc.edu/~rbrualdi/01-240exam2sol.pdf](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Erbrualdi/01-240exam2sol.pdf)
- https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/archive/118r_spring_99/doc/sol/1/sol1.pdf

Comment: In the other question you were told that the T4 fonts are basically only available as bitmap, which explains why they appear fainter on screen.

Comment: @egreg Ok then I change the title. I begin to think that the above looks are due to old compilers.

Comment: No, it's due to T4 encoded fonts only being available as bitmap. Nothing has changed in this respect.

Comment: @egreg But the examples I provided look different and are bitmap as well...

Comment: The document you refer to has been produced with different fonts (not T4).

Comment: @egreg Oh ok. But you do not happen to know which ones I assume?

Comment: I guess the standard Computer Modern fonts of 30 years ago.

Comment: See think question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100577/fatter-computer-modern

Comment: Your best bet is to simply play around with different fonts, and different weights. Use modern fonts. Do not bother with old ones, especially because (as you noted) they are not available everywhere. Keep in mind that print-to-paper from decades ago, especially if the book was produced using offset press (instead of digital press), will have visible character weights thicker than would be produced by digital press today, even with same fonts. Has to do with print technology, not TeX. In general, try fonts other than Computer Modern and Latin Modern.

Comment: `\documentstyle` is what they had before there was `\documentclass`. The font setup there predates the NFSS. Basically, those files are for LaTeX before 2e. `\font\BF cmbx10 scaled \magstep2` is setting up a standard, fixed TeX font, `\BF`, which will use the font `cmbx10` scaled to enlarge it. That is, it will use a scaled-up Computer Modern bold extended in 10pt. This will tend to make the font thicker because smaller sized fonts are typically thicker than the same points at higher pt sizes (where optical sizes are provided). This isn't the way to do things in current LaTeX.