# Newcomer wanting to work on Latex Programming Code

Tags: documentation

I would like to have a list of documents to read so that a newcomer can start working on Latex Programming.

What would be a good material sequence to read (e.g. described by documentation section names) and study ?

Naturally, on things that are freely available, no books to purchase.

Some have suggested the question

```
What is the best way to learn TeX?
```

But I want to focus on the latest way to program; for LATEX.

Comment: I learned many things from books I bought like the Texbook and the LaTeX companions and wonder why you think that you should get everything for free.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Firstly because it is the way of the future.  Read the article at https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-doc.html

Comment: And because you want to be compliant with the Free Software Guidelines on Debian Systems, which run the GNU System,

Comment: @Veak https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394492/1090 ....

Comment: Nothing stops you from releasing versions under the AGPL.  What are you worried about ?

Comment: nothing stops anyone doing that (this was discussed previously see the 1600 message thread on debian-legal before latex was listed as meeting the debian free software guidelines)

Comment: Does it have to be done by the Latex Team when you release the latest version of the code ? Do not get stuck on the idea of stopping people changing file names.  People know that the Official Latex Version is the one released by the Latex Team.  Or is it not ?

Comment: these comments are unrelated to your question, so this isn't the right forum

Comment: Fine.  @UlrikeFischer  Can argue that in a different question.

Comment: Which parts are useful in those answers ?  The answers are not direct, i.e. need to be just links with brief description.  And people would simply read that.

Comment: the question is whether the question is duplicate, you can always ask for new answers on the older questions, that's just how the site works.

Comment: And continue making it longer and longer !!!

Comment: I don't make the rules. This site is run by stackexchange, they define the mechanism.

Comment: I introduced a comment there requesting a very direct answer.

Comment: Fundamentally this is the same as previous questions: there are various resources listed, individuals may choose from such lists which they wish to pursue

Comment: Search for `\NewDocumentEnvironment` in `interface3.pdf`.  It is not there.  Neither it is in `Latex2e`.

Comment: @Veak I have no idea what you mean by "neither is it in latex2e" user level documentation for that is `texdoc usrguide` or documented source level in `texdoc source2e`

Comment: Is there a list of these texdocs (expl3, usrguide, source2e) with description somewhere ?

Comment: This is the basic frustration, all these different ones.  You should really have a single reference manual.

Comment: Just one reference for users (document authors) and one reference for developers.  That is what I meant.

Comment: sorry but "this is the future" is nonsense. You get a lot of stuff for free nowadays,  but there is no law that says that all good stuff must be free. I read news online but also pay for a paper. And I read town descriptions online but also pay for a guided tour.