# Why is my TeX font low-contrast? Can I change it?

Tags: fonts, typography

This is how text looks like in TeX:
[image]

Here's under magnification:[image]

This persists and looks about the same even when I print it out.

By comparison, here's how the text looks in Word (Calibri):[image]

And magnified:[image]

When reading the TeX paragraph, I feel like the letters are swimming before my eyes and can't be focused on. Is this font style on purpose, perhaps because it's easier to read in the long run, or is that an error in my configuration?

This happens even with the example here: http://mally.stanford.edu/~sr/computing/latex-example.html

Comment: That is a font choice issue, the screen shot you posted is for the default LaTeX font (Computer Modern) which you can change easily and use whatever font you like, even Calibri using XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX engines.

Comment: The mentioned feature is font-dependent, not tool-dependent. You can use Computer Modern in Word and you will see the same feature (problematic in your point of view) and you can use Calibri in TeX.

Comment: See the [LaTeX font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/), for example, if you need help choosing a different font.

Comment: Why should anybody want to replace a good readable Antiqua font with high redundancy by a less good readable Grotesque with less redundancy?

Comment: the question is just like choosing two different fonts in Word and asking why the output is different. It's not related to tex v word chose a serif font in Word or a sans serif in TeX (If you use xelatex or lualatex you could use system fonts so use exactly te font word is using)

Comment: There is an interesting similiar question here with  enlightening comments regarding the rasterization parameters of computer modern metafont sources, unfortunately I couldn't yet find it, maybe others could help find it?

Comment: @morbusg Perhaps you're thinking of [Are the original CM fonts better than the current type1 fonts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48369/are-the-original-cm-fonts-better-than-the-current-type1-fonts/361722#361722) or [It is possible to make fonts appear heavier (darker) in pdf output of Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110569/it-is-possible-to-make-fonts-appear-heavier-darker-in-pdf-output-of-latex) or one of the questions linked from them?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR yes, the first one, thank you for finding it!

Comment: or rather, writing the answer.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Yes, that is what I was looking for, thank you.