# Cannot search in document created with ps2pdf

Tags: ps2pdf

I've just converted an old paper with ps2pdf but while the result is legible, searching still does not work. It seems there are some invisible characters splitting the words.

Any advice on how to do the conversion differently?

Comment: German document? You might need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. But that's a guess, we need to see some code.

Comment: No, an english one. The .ps from here https://eprint.iacr.org/2003/069

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That PS file still uses the original (Metafont) bitmap fonts, and after conversion to PDF with `ps2pdf` you'll see something like this:

[image]

Such PDF files are not searchable (see e.g. [Are Knuth's fonts searchable in pdf yet?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/491882/82917)).

Since the source isn't available you can use the pkfix perl script ([CTAN link](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pkfix)) by Heiko Oberdiek (distributed with TeXLive; I don't know about MikTeX): it tries to replace the Type 3 fonts by the corresponding Type 1. Luckily it works on your file, so the combination

```
> pkfix 2003-069.ps 2003-069-fixed.ps
> ps2pdf 2003-069-fixed.ps
```

results in a file `2003-069-fixed.pdf` with Type 1 fonts

[image]

which is searchable.