# using special characters in csv file imported by pgfplotstable

Tags: unicode, pgfplotstable, input-encodings

I'm using `pgfplotstable` to render `CSV`-files as tables in my document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
ÄÖÜ!
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma, header=has colnames, verb string type]{test.csv}
\end{document}
```

That's working perfectly, until there are special characters in the external file. They cause errors in the first line, and are simply ignored in the following lines.

Here's my `test.csv`, which is encoded as `UTF-8`:

```
h1,öüä
d1,äöü
```

How can I make sure these characters render correctly?

Comment: It works for me if I add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and use `string type` instead of `verb string type`

Comment: I can confirm that. Since `fontenc` seems to have [additional benefits](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc), I'll look into using that.

Comment: I really need `verb`. Any way to make it work with that?

Comment: Could you give an example of the kind of stuff that will be in your table that needs `verb`?

Comment: Mostly e-mail-addresses containing `_`, probably some other reserved characters.

Comment: Email addresses *and* umlauts in the same column?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10026/discussion-between-fefrei-and-jake)