# Angle Quotes with English Text and English Figure and Table Labels

Tags: punctuation, languages, babel, font-encodings, csquotes

I use a standard package, `csquotes`, to handle quotes. But if I use it like in the MWE below, then in front of every table I get foreign language spelling for `figure` and `table` instead of English `figure` and `table`. Like here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, booktabs, setspace}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[top = 1in, bottom = 1in, left = 1in, right = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=russian]{csquotes}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.5, angle = 0]{Test}
        \caption{CAPTION GOES HERE}
            \label{fig:FIGURE NAME GOES HERE}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|llr|}
        \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} \\
            B & C & D (\$) \\
            \midrule
            E & F & G \\
            & H & I \\
            J & K & L \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
            \caption{CAPTION GOES HERE}
                \label{tab:TABLE NAME GOES HERE}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

If I replace `\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}` with        `\usepackage[russian, english]{babel}`, then get English text for figure and label, but the correct angle quotes get replaced with << and >> which are a little too low.

How do I need to configure my preamble to get English standard formatting everywhere except where `csquote` controls style of quotes? (I do this for my preferred readability, and an editor right now only needs to change the style in `csquote` to get English style quotes again.)

Comment: If you use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`, you wont need to tell anyone to replace the figure name with their own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to do with which fonts are being used for output.  Latex has a number of output encodings.  The standard is OT1, when Russian is selected you get T2A (the log file contains a warning that you should have set this up).  So if you quotes are only for parts of the text in Russian language then you can simply write:

```
 \foreignlanguage{russian}{\enquote{....}}
```

assuming you have selected main language English via `\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}`.  Here is a complete document.

[image: Sample ouptut]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,setspace}
\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=russian]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{A quote}
\foreignlanguage{russian}{\enquote{A quote}}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \rule{3cm}{2cm}
    \caption{Caption goes here}
    \label{fig:FIGURE NAME GOES HERE}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{llr}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{A} \\
    B & C & D (\$) \\
    \midrule
    E & F & G \\
    & H & I \\
    J & K & L \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption goes here}
  \label{tab:TABLE NAME GOES HERE}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand if you are just looking to use this style quote in English, you could load the (often preferable) T1 encoding:

```
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

This gives quotes that are a lot closer to the Russian T2A ones:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=russian]{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\enquote{A quote}
\foreignlanguage{russian}{\enquote{A quote}}
\end{document}
```

The advantage of turning T1 encoding on is that words with accents can now be hyphenated, see [Why should I use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664/15925).

Comment: Thank you. It worked and I will us T1 from now on in preambles. I have one question: Is there any reason to    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} instead of    \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} directly? Both actually work for english. And neither will affect math mode, which uses its own fonts that support it, yes?

Comment: Yes, maths uses its own encoding schemes.  Section 3 of the `fontenc` documentation explains that all encodings have to have standard English letters etc. in the standard positions, so this will work for English.  Just remember to write `caf\'e` not `café`