# Conflict with limit , font, babel

Tags: fonts, babel

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
$$\lim_{t\to a}{f(t)}$$
\end{document}
```

and the result is

[image]

I found that removing `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` the problem is solved, but I need to write in spanish and I like the font. are there some code like `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` which allows to use `tikz` and `spanish` together (`\usetikzlibrary{babel}` allows to use `<->` in draws with spanish babel)

Comment: May be `\unaccentedoperators` after the `babel` package?

Comment: @Manuel genius!! it works!, LaTeX has multiple and unknowed commands for everything.

Comment: Don't use `$$`, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you move `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to before `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` you get something that looks sort of correct, is this what you want?

[image: Spanish]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{gfsartemisia-euler}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$\lim_{t\to a}{f(t)}$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: **Question**: What does ´\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}´? because in Font Catalogue : http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/gfsartemisia-euler/ says add both,

Comment: I **think** `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` provides more detailed fonts. This thread: (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc) says that it adds more glyphs to the available characters. For example, without fontenc, the letter ö is created by putting dots over the letter o while with the package, there is an actual glyph for ö. Short story: the fonts are ugly without fontenc, according to my experience.

Answer (score 2):

Spanish `babel` offers a switch to have accented or unnacented operators (lim/lím, max/máx, min/mín, inf/ínf, mod/mód, etc.). It seems to work with the switch

```
\unaccentedoperators
```

In any case, I would wait for another answer because this just removes the addition made by `babel` leaving the original unaccented operators. There seems to be a problem with the accent char in a certain font loaded by `gfsartemisia-euler`, and it would be better to get an answer that *does* solve the problem (so you can have freedom between accented or unaccented operators).