# Specific packages for " é "?

Tags: accents

When just writing "een" or "1" the lines still work. 
They give error's as soon as I replace them with "é" because I want to put an emphasis on the "one".

I googled online and read wikibooks on special characters. I replaced the twho é's with \'{e} but it still gives an error as soon as i put this in.

Code Sample

```
{\documentclass[a7paper,print,10pt,grid=rear]{kartei}
%Voor info googelen op 'LaTeX kartei'
%a7paper: bepaalt hoe groot de fiches worden.  a6-a7-a8-a9 zijn de opties
%grid: geeft aan of er snijlijnen moeten geprint worden.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\antwoord}[1]  {%
  \vspace*{\fill}%
  \begin{center}
    #1
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}%
}

\newcommand{\vraag}[1]{#1}
\newsavebox\myimage
\sbox\myimage{%
  \includegraphics[scale=0.08]{zrm.png} %
}

\newcommand{\kaart}[2]{%
  \begin{karte}[Vraag]
    {\vraag{#1}}
    [\usebox\myimage]
    \answer{Antwoord}

    \antwoord{#2}

  \end{karte}%
}

\author{M.Brouwers}

\begin{document}



   \kaart{%
  $Onderstaande kubus heeft een inhoud van 512cm^{3}. Wat is de lengte van \'{e}\'{e}n ribbe?$

  \includegraphics[scale=1]{kubuszrm.png} }  {$ V = z^{3}$

  $ 512cm^{3} = z^{3} $

  $ We zoeken een getal dat tot de 3^{de} macht 512 $

  $ -> 8 $

  $ 512 cm^{3} = ( 8 cm )^{3}$

  De kubus heeft zijden van 8cm } 


\end{document}}
```

Comment: please provide a fully compilable example and please don't post pictures of your code, noone want to retype that code. Exactly which error? Is that code saved as UTF8?

Comment: Better like this?

Comment: Why the sentence “Onderstaande...” all in math mode? Where is the `kartei` class file available?

Comment: @egreg on [GitHub](https://github.com/kellertuer/Kartei) but you need to download all subfiles since the class definition is defined while calling sub-files... (!)

Comment: The error is because you have put everything in math mode, and `\'` is not allowed in math mode. Math mode should not be used for text, as it messes with spacing and puts everything in unkerned italics (so unless `\kaart` does something odd your example won't look any good if you remove `\'` anyway), so reserve it for the equations. If you want italics, use `\itshape` or `\textit{your text}`. The superscripts can be created with `\textsuperscript`.

Comment: @Michelle_B : great to see you're project continues! ||  Anyway, first, you need to save your file in the `utf8` format. || Then, it's better not to write regular text in math-mode (that is between `$`s): your error occurs because you tries to type accent in math-mode... || You should thus try `Onderstaande kubus heeft een inhoud van $512cm^{3}$. Wat is de lengte van één ribbe?` and `We zoeken een getal dat tot de $3^{de}$ macht 512 ` || To emphasis text, use rather `\emph{<your-text>}`

Comment: @ebo It's better to use `3\textsuperscript{de}` to avoid `de` being in math mode. Also, you can use `\mathrm{cm}`to get the units in upright text.

Comment: Haha yes @ebo it will continue untill I am done haha!

Comment: @ebo  i tried placing the  "   \'{e}\'{e}n    "  outside of the mathmode indicated by $. It worked! 
Thanks alot!

Comment: By the way, you should add the package `fontenc` if you plan to use accents, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664/47692.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you want this?

```
\documentclass[a7paper,print,10pt,grid=rear]{kartei}
%Voor info googelen op 'LaTeX kartei'
%a7paper: bepaalt hoe groot de fiches worden.  a6-a7-a8-a9 zijn de opties
%grid: geeft aan of er snijlijnen moeten geprint worden.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand{\antwoord}[1]  {%
  \vspace*{\fill}%
  \begin{center}
    #1
  \end{center}
  \vspace*{\fill}%
}

\newcommand{\vraag}[1]{#1}
\newsavebox\myimage
\sbox\myimage{%
  \includegraphics[scale=0.08]{zrm.png}%
}

\newcommand{\kaart}[2]{%
  \begin{karte}[Vraag]
    {\vraag{#1}}
    [\usebox\myimage]
    \answer{Antwoord}

    \antwoord{#2}

  \end{karte}%
}

\author{M.Brouwers}

\begin{document}

\kaart{%
Onderstaande kubus heeft een inhoud van \SI{512}{cm^{3}}. 
Wat is de lengte van \'{e}\'{e}n ribbe?

\includegraphics[scale=1]{kubuszrm.png} } {
  $ V = z^{3}$

  $ \SI{512}{cm^{3}} = z^{3} $

  We zoeken een getal dat tot de 3\textsuperscript{de} macht 512

  $ \to 8 $

  $ \SI{512}{cm^{3}} = ( \SI{8}{cm} )^{3}$

  De kubus heeft zijden van \SI{8}{cm} } 

\end{document}
```

Note that you should not have braces around the whole document. Math mode should be only used for math formulas, not for typesetting text.