# How do I avoid text from being pixelated?

Tags: font-encodings

MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % This seems to be the problem
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

If the `fontec` line is not commented out I get:

[image]

If I comment it out I get:

[image]

I need to use that package for the reasons given in [this Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/664/27256).

How can I get the quality of the second version while using the fontec package?

I am using TeXworks, but a colleague with LyX has the same results.

Comment: you don't have the scalable ec fonts installed which is odd but perhaps you can just do `\usepackage{lmodern}` and avoid the issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that indeed fixes it. would you like to write an answer? eventually adding a small how-to install (for noobs/dummies) the ec fonts?

Comment: If you want the scalable `ec` fonts, install `cm-super`.

Comment: @Bernard and how do I do that? the FAQ of the cm-super CTAN does not help much (and the readme is unavailable)

Comment: Which distribution do you have?

Comment: @Bernard ah, I think I understood. I am installing it through MiKTeX (I hope). thanks

Comment: Yes, it's not in the basic distribution. Insyall it via MiKTeX Package Manager, and probably run from the command line (as administrator) `updmap --verbose`.