# Odd effect of font encoding on titles, spacing, etc

Tags: fonts, spacing, font-encodings, letterspacing

My understanding of what

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

does is based on: [Why should I use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc)

In other words, I use it for better rendering of fonts for letters containing e.g. an Umlaut.

But it seems that the font encoding changes other things as well. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, final]{report}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem Ipsum Dolor}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut Labore (2011) et dolore magna Aliqua (2015). Ut enim ad minim veniam: $ x \odot y $, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat: $ x \otimes y $. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{document}
```

*With* \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}, the chapter title, and the section name itself, i.e. "Chapter 1", are rendered thinner and letters are spaced closely. *Without* loading it, section title letters are thicker, and spaced more apart.

There also seems to be a difference in overall spacing between letters in non-title text.

Any suggestions what the reason for this behavior is, and if there's maybe a problem behind it I didn't notice?

Comment: Different fonts are used. Also, the editor might show them slightly different.

Comment: @Johannes_B Output is also different in the pdf produced (would it make sense to add a screenshot to my question?).
If fonts are different, is there a way to manually set fonts s.t. output is identical, regardless of whether I use 'fontenc', for letters/symbols without special characters only, of course.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc#comment806_677

Comment: To clarify @Johannes_B’s comment: adding `\usepackage{lmodern}` after `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is a good remedy; with it, different fonts are used, which reproduce with much greater accuracy the metrics of the original Computer Modern font.  You will notice a different behavior in math formulas typeset at non-standard size, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

chapter in your setup uses a 24.88pt bold font. So one can demonstrate your issue with the following document, which clearly shows that the fonts are different:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, final]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}

\fontsize{24.88pt}{30pt}\selectfont \bfseries

Lorem Ipsum Dolor

\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont

Lorem Ipsum Dolor

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can find the reason if you look in the log-file or the fd-file:

The OT1-font is `cmbx12.pfb`: This is a 12pt font scaled up.

The T1-font is `sfbx2488.pfb` -- as the numbers indicate a native 24.88 pt.

Scaled up font normally looks bolder than fonts specifically designed for the size.

If you really prefer the bolder look, you can force latex to use a scaled up with T1-encoding too:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, final]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
   {%
      <5><6><7><8><9>gen*ecbx%
      <10><10.95>ecbx1000%
      <12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>ecbx1200%
   }{}
\begin{document}\pagestyle{empty}

\fontsize{24.88pt}{30pt}\selectfont \bfseries

Lorem Ipsum Dolor

\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont

Lorem Ipsum Dolor

\end{document}
```

[image]