# Get correct typesetting in math-escape mode in listings

Tags: math-mode, listings

Within a `listings` environment I want to do `$\text{\ttfamily\_}$`within mathescape. The reason for wanting to do that is to be able to use `\left` and `\right`when doing some pseudocode style. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  mathescape
}
\begin{document}
\bgroup
  \begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
    $\displaystyle\left(\sum_i\text{\ttfamily my\_var}\right)$:
    $\texttt{my\_var}\neq$ my_var because $\texttt\_\neq$_
  \end{lstlisting}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Output of example code]

In the output above, the kerning between the letters are off, as well as the underscore thickness. I can live with the kerning, but I need the underscore fixed. Any suggestions?

Thanks :D

Comment: `columns=fullflexible`

Comment: @egreg that fixes the kerning! Nice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the underscore use T1-encoding. The spacing in the listings is set/added by listings, so you would need to adjust this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  mathescape
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\bgroup
  \begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
    $\displaystyle\left(\sum_i\text{\ttfamily my\_var}\right)$:
    $\texttt{my\_var}\neq$ my_var because $\texttt\_\neq$_
  \end{lstlisting}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If one however decided to ignore [Why you should use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/677/85834) and just wanted a dirty fix to use the `fontenc` in the listings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  mathescape,
  columns=fullflexible%<- Letter kerning fix from @egreg's comment
}
\begin{document}
\bgroup
  \fontencoding{T1}%<- Temporary change font encoding (not recommended)
  \begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
    $\displaystyle\left(\sum_i\text{\ttfamily my\_var}\right)$:
    $\texttt{my\_var}=$ my_var because $\texttt\_=$_
  \end{lstlisting}
\egroup
\end{document}
```