# Lettrine package: can't copy/paste text on the first lines

Tags: lettrine

When using the lettrine package, I can't copy/paste the text on the first few lines (tested with Okular 21.04).

[image]

while it does work on the next lines:

[image]

This also make the document harder to annotate since the selected text is not the good one.

Is it possible to solve that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{lmodern} % vector font
%% Language
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%% Input encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%% Output encoding https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/677. Important to copy accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
\LettrineRealHeighttrue
\setlength{\DefaultNindent}{0em}
\renewcommand*{\DefaultLhang}{0.33}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\fontshape{sc}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}

\lettrine{H}{ello world}, \lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how far this is a TeX issue. It works for me with PDF-XChange, so this might be a problem of okular, not `lettrine`.

Comment: Works OK with Acrobat Reader DC.

Comment: Okular-related. Okular 20.12.2 for Windows (latest version from Microsoft Store) leaves off the "H", but can copy everything else, including page number.