# Option add a node to any point in a circuit?

Tags: circuitikz

Was wondering if there is a way to add a node to a circuit drawn with "circuitikz" at any point.  However, if I would, for example, change the bottom-left node of my circuit to point downwards instead?  Is there an option to just move the component on the line or add a line with a node? I was lucky this time since I could organise, but curious to know this for another time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 1.5]
\draw
(-4,0) to[R,l=$\mathcal{R_1}$,o-o] (2,0)
(0,0) to[R,l=$\mathcal{R_2}$,-*] (0,2)
(-4,2) to[R,l=$\mathcal{R_3}$,o-o] (2,2)
(-2,2) to[R,l=$\mathcal{R_4}$,-*] (-2,4)
(-4,4) to[R,l=$\mathcal{R_5}$,o-o] (2,4)
(0,4) to[R,l=$\mathcal{R_6}$,-*] (0,6)
(-4,6) to[R,l=$\mathcal{R_7}$,o-o] (2,6)
(-2,0) to[american current source,*-*,l=$\Phi_1$] (-2,2)
(-2,4) to[american current source,*-*,l=$\Phi_2$] (-2,6)
;
\end{circuitikz}
    \caption{Unit equivalent circuit of permeance network}
    \label{fig:magcircuit}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not related, but I suppose you want `\mathcal{R}_1`, there are no numbers in `mathcal` font. And probably you'll need `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure if I understood your question --- if not, please sketch what you need. Anyway, if for nodes you mean the filled poles (that's the name used in the manual, to avoid confusion with Ti*k*Z nodes), you can put them where you need with

```
\node[circ] at (3,3) {};
```

or along a path

```
\draw ... (3,3) node[circ]{} ...
```

Another option is to use a wire or an open with poles:

```
\draw (0,0) to[short, o-*] (1,1) to[open, *] (2,2);
```

Anyway, I would draw it like this; using relative coordinates and coordinates names you can then stretch and shrink things just changing one number.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
\begin{circuitikz}[scale = 1.5, american]
\draw
(0,0) coordinate(start) 
    to[short, o-] ++(0,1) -- ++(2,0) coordinate(phi1r1)
    to[R,l=$\mathcal{R}_1$,*-*] ++(2,0) coordinate (r1r2)
    to[short, -o] ++(2,0) coordinate(bot1)
    % phi
    (phi1r1) to[I, l=$\Phi_1$, -*] ++(0,2) coordinate(phi1r3)
    % node to the right above the first one
    to [short, -o] (phi1r3 -| start) % perpendicular coords
    (phi1r3) to[R,l=$\mathcal{R}_3$,-*] (phi1r3 -| r1r2)
    to [short, -o] (phi1r3 -| bot1)
    (r1r2) to[R,l=$\mathcal{R}_2$] (phi1r3 -| r1r2)
;
\end{circuitikz}
    \caption{Unit equivalent circuit of permeance network}
    \label{fig:magcircuit}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]