# Text goes over page end

Tags: alignment, text, paracol

Somehow suddenly the text of my work is going over the rim of the page. It never does that before. Maybe a \usepackage is missed. I could not find the answer so far.

[image]

Usually it looks like this.

[image]

```
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=3cm, bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize, labelfont=bf, textfont=it,skip=2pt]{caption}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx}
\usepackage{paracol}
```

I am doing a paracol part with switch column on this part. Maybe that is somehow a problem for the program?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Can you please post a full (yet minimal) self-contained example? We don't know what class you are using, or in fact what text you are trying to set. Mentioning a few of the packages you are using doesn't really help.

Comment: Wild guess: forgot to load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` --- and so no word with non-ascii letter get no hyphenation? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc (all the protruding lines have accented letters around...)

Comment: The `ngerman` package is beyond obsolete. Use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} instaed.