# Footnotes in table not numbered properly

Tags: footnotes, tabularray

I'd like to add a footnote in an array, but the numbering is bad. Any idea what's wrong?

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
% https://ctan.crest.fr/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfiles/subfiles.pdf
\usepackage{lmodern} % vector font
\usepackage[english]{babel}%
%% Input encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%% Output encoding https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/677. Important to copy accents
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum} % For tests, use like \lipsum[1-5] to write 5 paragraphs
%%% ========== Usual packages ==========

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\usepackage{tabularray} % Nice tabular (like booktabs, but with colors and more). Only in recent CTAN.
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Blabla \footnote{First note}
Blabla \footnote{Second note}


\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={c},
    }%,
    \toprule
    Related Works\\
    \hline[.6pt,white]
    Blabla\protect\footnotemark{}\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{tab:comparisonRelatedWorks}
\end{table}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext{Footnote in table.}


Blabla \footnote{Last note}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `tblr` evaluates the content many times to get the best layout so your counter is being increased. use optional argument to `\footnotemark` to force the number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copunters issues is handled by Tblr Library `counter`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[vmargin=99mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, booktabs, counter}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Blabla \footnote{First note}
Blabla \footnote{Second note}


\begin{table}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tblr}{
      colspec={c},
    }%,
    \toprule
    Related Works\\
    \hline[.6pt,white]
    Blabla\footnotemark{}\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tblr}
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{tab:comparisonRelatedWorks}
\end{table}
\footnotetext{Footnote in table.}

Blabla \footnote{Last note}
\end{document}
```

[image]