# Tabularray with footnotes

Tags: footnotes, tabularray

I'm almost done switching to `tabularray` but have just one final problem to solve.

Using `\footnote` inside `tblr` doesn't work properly, but it's a known problem with most (all?) table-like environments. After a bit of research, I tried this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{footnote}
\makesavenoteenv{tblr}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={ll}}
a line & a text\footnote{with a note} in the middle\\
another line & another text\footnote{with another note} in the middle
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to `\UseTblrLibrary{counter}`, the footnotes are numbered correctly inside the table, but the footnotes themselves are badly handled and appear multiple times:

[image: Result1]

Second try, I used `\TblrNote` provided by `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
    note{1}={with a note},
    note{2}={with another note}
]{colspec={ll}}
a line & a text\TblrNote{1} in the middle\\
another line & another text\TblrNote{2} in the middle
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

which yields this:

[image: Result2]

But this solution isn't satisfactory for several reasons:

- The footnote numbers in the table don't handle spaces after them correctly, as shown in the picture above.
- I'd have to number footnotes manually, which is a big no-no in LaTeX.
- The footnotes themselves aren't rendered like normal footnotes: wrong font size, no horizontal rule above them, and their numbers ignore previously existing footnotes on other pages.

Is there a clean way to get real footnotes with `tabularray`? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327385/230596

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but unless I'm mistaken this solution doesn't use `tabularray`. As I explained at the beginning of my post, the very point is to completely switch to this package. Also, it seems to create notes attached to the table instead of the page.

Comment: Does this so,Union help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636963/footnotes-in-table-not-numbered-properly

Comment: Yes, I did see this page when I searched. The problem is that this solution is mostly a "quick'n' dirty hack", requiring manual tinkering each time I have a footnote in a table. If I keep using `tabular`, I just load the `footnote` package and everything is handled cleanly and automatically. I'm wondering if I can get to this point with `tabularray`.

Comment: tabularray  processes the body more than once but currently misses a suitable interface to distinguish (and hook into) the measuring phase from the typesetting phase. https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/179.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Does this mean that there is no clean way to handle footnotes at this time? I'm just curious, if it's the case, I'll just revert to good ol' tabular when I need footnotes. For the huge majority of my usecases, tabularray passed with flying colors.

Comment: I don't think so. Also imho for such simple tabulars as in your example using tabularray is overdoing. As you can see from the footnotes (or if you remove the counter library) it typesets some parts quite often.  This can slow down the compilation noticably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to update your documents or TeX distribution if your documents work well. In fact, most of my documents are still using traditional `tabular` environment, compiled on a 10 year old MiKTeX distribution. :-)

---

Anyway, here is a possible solution. With the newly added `functional` library you can split each footnote into `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, then add footnote text after the table with some hook. Maybe it is not perfect, but at least it works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}

\makeatletter
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\tlNew \gFootNoteTl
\intNew \gFootNoteInt
\prgNewFunction \footNote {m}
  {
    \tlPutRight \gFootNoteTl
      {
        \stepcounter{footnote}
        \footnotetext{#1}
      }
    \prgReturn {\footnotemark{}}
  }
\AddToHook{env/tblr/before}{
  \intSetEq \gFootNoteInt \c@footnote
  \tlClear \gFootNoteTl
}
\AddToHook{env/tblr/after}{
  \intSetEq \c@footnote \gFootNoteInt
  \tlUse \gFootNoteTl
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some note\footnote{some note} before.

\bigskip

\begin{tblr}[evaluate=\footNote]{colspec={ll},hlines}
a line & a text\footNote{with a note} in the middle\\
another line & another text\footNote{with another note} in the middle
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

\begin{tblr}[evaluate=\footNote]{colspec={ll},hlines}
a line & a text\footNote{with a note} in the middle\\
another line & another text\footNote{with another note} in the middle
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

Another note\footnote{another note} after.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I know I don't *have* to update everything, but I like `tabularrray` syntax better, and when I find a good replacement for a tool, I usually want to get rid of the old one as fast as possible. Call if irrational. As for your answer, I've never played with `functional`, this might be a good starting point.

Comment: @Miyase You can find some examples of `functional` library from https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/81

Comment: Well, the "only" issue with tabularray is that it compiles kind of slowly -- but (I assume the bottleneck is with the boxing instead of the token-processing part, didn't actually measure) it's not a built-in like halign so can't compete...

Comment: The \footnotetext command in the function does not seem to work, i.e., it does not produce any footnote. The hooks can be seen to be evaluated. My guess is that the \footnotetext command needs to be invoked outside environments, including tabularray ones. This is speaking of tabularray 2022-06-01 v2022B.

Answer (score 3):

I want to add another answer to make some explanations of the table notes in `talltblr` or `longtblr` in `tabularray` package.

The `\TblrNote` command is similar to `\tnote` in `threeparttable` package and `\tnotex` in `threeparttablex` package. Table notes are different from footnotes. They are put after the tables. So it is better not to mix them with footnotes. Many users choose to use alphabet values (a,b,c,...) as note marks.

You need to specify the note mark in `\TblrNote` command, but there is an advantage that you can give the same note mark in different `\TblrNote` (see the example below). Some users think this is useful.

Also by default `\TblrNote` command `\rlap` the note mark (It is also the default setup of `\tnote` and `\tnotex` commands in `threeparttable` and `\threeparttablex` packages). One of the reasons is that it makes `siunitx` numbers align well (see the example below).

You can change the default setting by redefine `\TblrOverlap` command.

```
\renewcommand\TblrOverlap[1]{#1}
```

The above code line removes the default `\rlap` setting.

---

Now here is a complete example showing the usages of `\TblrNote` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {First Table},
  note{a} = {with a note},
  note{b} = {with another note}
]{
  colspec = {S[table-format=3.2]S[table-format=3.2]},
  row{1} = {guard}
}
\toprule
  Some Head Text     & Some Head Text     \\
\midrule
  111.22             & 111.22\TblrNote{a} \\
  222.33\TblrNote{b} & 222.33             \\
  333.44             & 333.44\TblrNote{b} \\
\bottomrule
\end{talltblr}

\vspace{2em}

\renewcommand\TblrOverlap[1]{#1}

\begin{talltblr}[
  caption = {Second Table},
  note{a} = {with a note},
  note{b} = {with another note}
]{colspec={ll}}
\hline
a line & a text\TblrNote{a} in the middle             \\
another line & another text\TblrNote{b} in the middle \\
\hline
\end{talltblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is just a tiny modification of the L.J.R. answer, that works with `longtblr`, i.e.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}

\makeatletter
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\tlNew \gFootNoteTl
\intNew \gFootNoteInt
\prgNewFunction \footNote {m}
  {
    \tlPutRight \gFootNoteTl
      {
        \stepcounter{footnote}
        \footnotetext{#1}
      }
    \prgReturn {\footnotemark{}}
  }
\AddToHook{env/longtblr/before}{
  \intSetEq \gFootNoteInt \c@footnote
  \tlClear \gFootNoteTl
}
\AddToHook{env/longtblr/after}{
  \intSetEq \c@footnote \gFootNoteInt
  \tlUse \gFootNoteTl
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some note\footnote{some note} before.

\bigskip

\begin{longtblr}[evaluate=\footNote]{colspec={ll},hlines}
a line & a text\footNote{with a note} in the middle\\
another line & another text\footNote{with another note} in the middle
\end{longtblr}

\bigskip

Another note\footnote{another note} after.

\end{document}
```

[image]