# Footnote does not work with "longtblr"

Tags: footnotes, longtblr

How to make `\footnote{}` work within `longtblr`?

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{
      hlines,
      vlines,
      colspec   = {X[1]X[3]},
      rowhead   = 1,
      rowsep    = 0.5ex,
      width     = 0.9\linewidth,
      row{1}    = {font=\bfseries}
    }
    Header       & Second header\\
    First column & Second column\footnote{Hello!}\\
    First column & Second column\\
    First column & Second column\\
    First column & Second column\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to implement table-notes? Like the following example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
note{a} = {Hello!},
]{
      hlines,
      vlines,
      colspec   = {X[1]X[3]},
      rowhead   = 1,
      rowsep    = 0.5ex,
      width     = 0.9\linewidth,
      row{1}    = {font=\bfseries}
    }
    Header       & Second header\\
    First column & Second column\TblrNote{a}\\
    First column & Second column\\
    First column & Second column\\
    First column & Second column\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Based on the comments, OP wants actual footnotes in the longtblr environment. Then you can try the accepted answer to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645421/tabularray-with-footnotes).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mane32... I was thinking about an actual footnote... but if footnote does not work within longtblr, I could use your solution as a temporary workaround... :-) My desire would be to add a footnote with the note at the end of the page and not at the end of the table....if possible....

Comment: For future readers, I added an answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645421/tabularray-with-footnotes/712683#712683 which is exactly about how to add a footnote within ```longtblr```. It is just a small modification of the @L.J.R. answer (the accepted one)