# How to remove or reduce the whitespace between the end of longtblr and the note created with \TblrNote?

Tags: notes, longtblr

How to remove or reduce the whitespace between the end of `longtblr` and the note created with `\TblrNote{}`?
This is a follow up question from the accepted answer given by @Mane32 in [Footnote does not work with "longtblr"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712672/footnote-does-not-work-with-longtblr/712674#712674):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
note{a} = {Hello!},
]{
      hlines,
      vlines,
      colspec   = {X[1]X[3]},
      rowhead   = 1,
      rowsep    = 0.5ex,
      width     = 0.9\linewidth,
      row{1}    = {font=\bfseries}
    }
    Header       & Second header\\
    First column & Second column\TblrNote{a}\\
    First column & Second column\\
    First column & Second column\\
    First column & Second column\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Maybe, a new command needs to be defined starting from the original one in the [tabularray documentation (pag.146)](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) (but I am not able to):

```
\NewDocumentCommand \TblrNote { m }
 {
 \cs_if_exist:NT \hypersetup { \ExpTblrTemplate { note-border }{ default } }
 \TblrOverlap
 {
 \__tblr_hyper_link:nn {#1}
 { \textsuperscript { \sffamily \UseTblrFont { note-tag } #1 } }
 }
```