# The footnote text is repeated several times at the bottom of the page

Tags: footnotes, longtblr

Why is the footnote text repeated several times at the bottom of the page?

How to get the footnote text only once? (and not 6 times as in the following example)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645421/tabularray-with-footnotes/712683#712683
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}

\makeatletter
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\tlNew \gFootNoteTl
\intNew \gFootNoteInt
\prgNewFunction \footNote {m}
  {
    \tlPutRight \gFootNoteTl
      {
        \stepcounter{footnote}
        \footnotetext{#1}
      }
    \prgReturn {\footnotemark{}}
  }
\AddToHook{env/longtblr/before}{
  \intSetEq \gFootNoteInt \c@footnote
  \tlClear \gFootNoteTl
}
\AddToHook{env/longtblr/after}{
  \intSetEq \c@footnote \gFootNoteInt
  \tlUse \gFootNoteTl
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt
]{
  colspec = {lX},
  colsep=4pt,
  hline{odd}={solid},
  row{odd}={belowsep=0pt},
  row{even}={abovesep=0pt},
  cell{even}{1} = {c=2}{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j}
}
    01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
    01/01/2018 $-$ 31/12/2019 \footNote{my footnote} & \textbf{Second}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
    01/01/2016 $-$ 31/12/2017 & \textbf{Third}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDITED after the comments of @daleif and @gusbrs, who I thank a lot!**

The moving of `\prgReturn {\footnotemark{}}` outside the `\IfBooleanF` condition, impedes the footnote symbol to go down to the following line in the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645421/tabularray-with-footnotes/712683#712683
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}

\makeatletter
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\tlNew \gFootNoteTl
\intNew \gFootNoteInt
\prgNewFunction \footNote {m}
  {
    \IfBooleanF { \lTblrMeasuringBool }
      {
        \tlPutRight \gFootNoteTl
          {
            \stepcounter{footnote}
            \footnotetext{#1}
          }
        %\prgReturn {\footnotemark{}}  % <-- Before
      }
      \prgReturn {\footnotemark{}} % <-- Now
  }
\AddToHook{env/longtblr/before}{
  \intSetEq \gFootNoteInt \c@footnote
  \tlClear \gFootNoteTl
}
\AddToHook{env/longtblr/after}{
  \intSetEq \c@footnote \gFootNoteInt
  \tlUse \gFootNoteTl
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt
]{
  colspec = {lX},
  colsep=4pt,
  hline{odd}={solid},
  row{odd}={belowsep=0pt},
  row{even}={abovesep=0pt},
  cell{even}{1} = {c=2}{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j}
}
    01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
    01/01/2018 $-$ 31/12/2019 \footNote{my footnote} & \textbf{Second}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
    01/01/2016 $-$ 31/12/2017 & \textbf{Third}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should table notes come right after the table anyways?

Comment: If you add `\typeout{foo}` to `\footNote` you can see that it gets executed 6 times. Presumably for measuring etc. `align` from `amsmath` does something similar (runs twice) but has a setting one can test for to see if we are in a measuring state. Perhaps this has something similar (have not checked)

Comment: Thanks @daleif :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tabularray` tables perform a number of measuring passes before getting its final typeset form, so your footnote gets typeset every pass. You can test for measuring passes with `\lTblrMeasuringBool`:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularray}


% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/645421/tabularray-with-footnotes/712683#712683
\UseTblrLibrary{counter}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional}

\makeatletter
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\tlNew \gFootNoteTl
\intNew \gFootNoteInt
\prgNewFunction \footNote {m}
  {
    \IfBooleanF { \lTblrMeasuringBool }
      {
        \tlPutRight \gFootNoteTl
          {
            \stepcounter{footnote}
            \footnotetext{#1}
          }
        \prgReturn {\footnotemark{}}
      }
  }
\AddToHook{env/longtblr/before}{
  \intSetEq \gFootNoteInt \c@footnote
  \tlClear \gFootNoteTl
}
\AddToHook{env/longtblr/after}{
  \intSetEq \c@footnote \gFootNoteInt
  \tlUse \gFootNoteTl
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  presep=-4pt,postsep=0pt
]{
  colspec = {lX},
  colsep=4pt,
  hline{odd}={solid},
  row{odd}={belowsep=0pt},
  row{even}={abovesep=0pt},
  cell{even}{1} = {c=2}{wd=\textwidth-8pt,halign=j}
}
    01/01/2020 $-$ 31/12/2022 & \textbf{First}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
    01/01/2018 $-$ 31/12/2019 \footNote{my footnote} & \textbf{Second}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
    01/01/2016 $-$ 31/12/2017 & \textbf{Third}\\
    \lipsum[2] &\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, however, that the MWE above is "proof of principle", it is not quite good enough, because I disabled the footnote completely in the measuring passes, and you actually should include the mark in those passes not to throw the measurement off by the width of the mark itself. But I did not quite understand what you were trying to do there, so I just disabled it.

Comment: It seems enough if you move `\prgReturn {\footnotemark{}}` out of the boolean test, at least then the footnote number **should** be there during the measuring. Though in this case it does not matter much, but would matter if the footnote was in the text part.

Comment: @daleif I suppose so, but I'm unacquainted with this `functional` library and have no idea of what `\prgReturn` is supposed to be. So I preferred being explicit about my ignorance, and just left the warning.  ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: @gusbrs I have noticed that the footnote symbol inside the table goes to the following line (in this case is partially covered by the text of ```\lipsum```)..How to leave it just beside the date?

Comment: @Ommo That's an effect of the measuring problem stated in the answer. The width is calculated without the mark, so it falls on the next line. As mentioned to daleif, I don't quite know `functional` and have no idea what `\prgReturn` is. So you have to figure that out, the answer tells you how to distinguish measuring passes from the final one. A simple test suggests that daleif's suggestion works (just moving `\prgReturn {\footnotemark{}}` out of the boolean test). But you must know if that's what you really want to do.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks! ```\makeatletter
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\tlNew \gFootNoteTl
\intNew \gFootNoteInt
\prgNewFunction \footNote {m}
  {
    \IfBooleanF { \lTblrMeasuringBool }
      {
        \tlPutRight \gFootNoteTl
          {
            \stepcounter{footnote}
            \footnotetext{#1}
          }
      }
      \prgReturn {\footnotemark{}}
  }
\AddToHook{env/longtblr/before}{
  \intSetEq \gFootNoteInt \c@footnote
  \tlClear \gFootNoteTl
}
\AddToHook{env/longtblr/after}{
  \intSetEq \c@footnote \gFootNoteInt
  \tlUse \gFootNoteTl
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\makeatother```

Comment: Many thanks to @daleif and @gusbrs!! I edited my question, with your suggestion