Cirkuitikz: How to only rotate alternating current symbol?
I'm tasked with correcting some minor issues with my recent lab report. One of those issues consists of a wrong orientation of the alternating current symbol; I know the wave is supposed to be aligned horizontally, but I couldn't find any helpful advice on how to achieve that with my current code situation online, even prior to turning my report in, so I hoped it might be correct this way...which it wasn't. (Pictures below)
This is my code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
%=======================
\begin{document}
%=======================
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,2) to[sV, o-] (1,2) to[R, l=$R_1$, a=\SI{10}{\kilo\ohm}] (3,2);
    \draw (3,2)  to [short, -o] (6,2);
    \draw (4,2) to[C, l=$C_1 \quad ~~~ U_a(t)$, a=\SI{10}{\nano\farad}, *-] (4,0) to [short, -*] (4,0);
    \draw (4,0) to [short, -o] (0,0);
    \draw (4,0) to [short, -o] (6,0);
    \node at (0,1) [align=center] {$U_{e}(t)$};
\end{circuitikz}
    \caption{Verwendeter Schaltkreis mit R-C-Glied und den Größen für R und C}
    \label{fig:circuit_tiefpass}
\end{figure}
%=======================
\end{document}

Which produces the following image:

But I need it to look like this instead:

P.S.:

Yes I know my code is written poorly, that's because I'm a noob
The only way I found to have the correct orientation was to have the circuit be a connected loop, but I specifically want it to be in this split up representation (if possible), since that's how I presented it to the lab tutors when explaining what my experiment is going to be
I already tried out "rotate" but that leads to weird results, such as this one:


I'm happy to read your suggestions and I'm sending out huge thanks to anybody in advance :O)

Welcome to TeX StackExchange!

welcome!
Ok, first of all: you should use a minimal example. In your case, that could be:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[sV, o-] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

which gives(*):

If you go to page 76 of the manual, about "customization for sources", you can find:

So a solution can be:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[sV, o-, sources/symbol/rotate=auto] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

which gives you:

If this is what you want, you can simply (instead of doing it for every source) add
\ctikzset{sources/symbol/rotate=auto}

in your preamble, like:
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{sources/symbol/rotate=auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,0) to[sV, o-] ++(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

which will give the same result as before.
So your final circuit will be:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{sources/symbol/rotate=auto}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{float}
%=======================
\begin{document}
%=======================
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,2) to[sV, o-] (1,2) to[R, l=$R_1$, a=\SI{10}{\kilo\ohm}] (3,2);
    \draw (3,2)  to [short, -o] (6,2);
    \draw (4,2) to[C, l=$C_1 \quad ~~~ U_a(t)$, a=\SI{10}{\nano\farad}, *-] (4,0) to [short, -*] (4,0);
    \draw (4,0) to [short, -o] (0,0);
    \draw (4,0) to [short, -o] (6,0);
    \node at (0,1) [align=center] {$U_{e}(t)$};
\end{circuitikz}
    \caption{Verwendeter Schaltkreis mit R-C-Glied und den Größen für R und C}
    \label{fig:circuit_tiefpass}
\end{figure}
%=======================
\end{document}


Notice that the space you are giving to the generator (1 units, which is 1 cm by default) is too small for a nice display (the pole is almost touching the generator).

(*) sorry for the awful image, but SE decided I can't post an image smaller than 160x160 px... 

Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was looking for! I also looked at the source you provided, but must have overlooked that part, sorry :/

You're welcome. Unrelated, but you should read also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc
